# sale el siguiente error rying to get property '0' of non-object al hacer submit en un formulario en un proyecto laravel 8 ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Tags: javascript, laravel

Estoy desarrollando un modulo de insumos, que consiste que a la hora de crear un insumo halla otro formulario donde se le agregue unas entradas y al momento de agregar estas entradas se aumenta la cantidad de ese insumo que se esta creando, la vista quedaría de la siguiente manera =  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error es que al momento de hacer submit en el formulario me sale ese error Trying to get property '0' of non-object, el modulo esta compuesto de la siguiente manera =

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los modelos se ven de la siguiente manera =
insumo:

```
  class Insumo extends Model
    {
        public $timestamps = false;
        use HasFactory;
        protected $table ='insumo';
        protected  $guarded = [];
        protected $fillable = ['nombre','estatus','medida','stock_minimo','cantidad'];
    
    }
```

entrada:

```
   class Entrada extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table ='entrada';
    protected $fillable = ['cantidad','lote','caducidad'];
}
```

entrada-insumo

```
class insumo_entrada extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['idInsumo','idEntrada'];
    use HasFactory;
    public function insumos(){
        return $this->hasMany(Insumo::class );
    }
    public function entrada(){
        return $this->hasMany(Entrada::class );
    }
}
```

El método guardar en el controlador =

```
   public function save(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            $insumo = Insumo::create([
                "nombre" => $input["nombre"],
                "estatus" => $input["estatus"],
                "medida" => $input["medida"],
                "stock_minimo" => $input["stock_minimo"],
                "cantidad" => $this->calcular_cantidad($input["entrada_id"], $input["cantidades"]),
            ]);
            foreach($input["entrada_id[]"] as $key => $value){
                insumo_entrada::create([
                    "idEntrada"=>$value,
                    "idInsumo"=>$insumo->id,
                    "cantidades"
                ]);
            }
            DB::commit();
            return redirect("insumos/Listar")->with('mensaje','creacion completada');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack();
            return redirect("insumos/insumoCrear")->with('mensaje', $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Formulario HTML =

```
 @if(session('mensaje'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{session('mensaje')}}
        </div>
    @endif
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h3 class="text-center">Crear insumo <a href="/producto/listar"> Listar</a></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form action="{{route('CrearInsumo')}}" method="post">
        @csrf
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-head">
                        <h4 class="text-center">1. Info insumos</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row card-body">
                        <div class="form-group col-6">
                            <label for="">Nombre</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-6">
                            <label for="estatus">Marque (1 si esta activo) (0 si esta inactivo)</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="estatus" name="estatus">
                                <option>0</option>
                                <option>1</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-6">
                            <label for="">Medida</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="medida">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-6">
                            <label for="">Stock_minimo</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="stock_minimo">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-6">
                            <label for="">Cantidad</label>
                            <input type="number" id="cantidad_total" class="form-control" name="cantidad" readonly>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12" style="margin-top: 3%;">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Guardar</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-head">
                        <h4 class="text-center">2. Info entradas</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row card-body">
                        <div class="col-5">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="">Lote</label>
                                <select name="entrada" id="entrada" class="form-control" onchange="colocar_campos()">
                                    <option value="">Seleccione</option>
                                    @foreach($entradas as $value)
                                        <option lote="{{ $value->lote }}" caducidad="{{ $value->caducidad }}" cantidad="{{ $value->cantidad }}"  value="{{ $value->id }}">{{ $value->lote }}
                                        </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="">Cantidad</label>
                                <input type="number" id="cantidad"  class="form-control" readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="">Caducidad</label>
                                <input id="caducidad" type="date"  class="form-control" readonly >
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <button onclick="agregar_entrada()" type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-success float-right">Agregar</button>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>lote</th>
                            <th>Cantidad</th>
                            <th>Caducidad</th>
                            <th>Subtotal</th>
                            <th>Opciones</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="tblEntradas">

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
```

formulario js =

```
@section('js')
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("select").select2();
        });
        function colocar_campos() {
            let cantidad = $("#entrada option:selected").attr("cantidad");
            $("#cantidad").val(cantidad);
            let caducidad = $("#entrada option:selected").attr("caducidad");
            $("#caducidad").val(caducidad);
        }
function agregar_entrada(){
    let entrada_id = $("#entrada option:selected").val();
    let entrada_text = $("#entrada option:selected").text();
    let cantidad = $("#cantidad").val();
    let caducidad = $("#caducidad").val();

        if (cantidad>0) {
            $("#tblEntradas").append(`
                    <tr id="tr-${entrada_id}">
                        <td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="entrada_id[]" value="${entrada_id}" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="cantidades[]" value="${cantidad}" />
                            ${entrada_text}
                        </td>
                        <td>${cantidad}</td>
                        <td>${caducidad}</td>
                        <td>${parseInt(cantidad) + parseInt(cantidad)}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminar_entrada(${entrada_id}, ${parseInt(cantidad) + parseInt(cantidad)})">X</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                `);
            let cantidad_total = $("#cantidad_total").val() || 0;
            $("#cantidad_total").val(parseInt(cantidad_total) + parseInt(cantidad) + parseInt(cantidad));
        } else {
            alert("Se debe ingresar una cantidad ");
        }
       }
        function eliminar_entrada(id, subtotal) {
            $("#tr-" + id).remove();
            let cantidad_total = $("#cantidad_total").val() || 0;
            $("#cantidad_total").val(parseInt(cantidad_total) - subtotal);
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sería útil saber en qué punto estás obteniendo dicho error para estar seguros, pero con lo que compartes, el único punto en donde veo que podría salirte ese error es aquí:

```
"idInsumo"=>$insumo->id
```

Lo cual me lleva a pensar que algo está fallando en tu `Insumo::create` porque la variable $insumo debería ser un objeto... Podría sugerirte que antes de `foreach($input["entrada_id[]"]` valides si el registro de insumo se creó correctamente.

Otra opción es que cambies tu "create" por lo siguiente:

```
$insumo = new Insumo();
$insumo->nombre = $input["nombre"];
$insumo->estatus = $input["estatus"];
$insumo->medida = $input["medida"];
$insumo->stock_minimo = $input["stock_minimo"];
$insumo->cantidad = $this->calcular_cantidad($input["entrada_id"], $input["cantidades"]);
$insumo->save();
```

Comment: Es mejor no dar respuestas a preguntas que necesitan una aclaración, pues la respuesta será casi siempre adivinando y Bienvenid@ a SOes!

Comment: Entiendo, Christian. Lamentablemente, en SO/es no tengo suficiente reputación para hacer un comentario sobre la pregunta, que hubiera sido mi primera opción, así es que no me quedó de otra que postear la respuesta directamente, aunque haya sido adivinando :(

Comment: bro gracias al menos por responder algo gracias a lo que escribiste puede ver una especie de solución pero ahora tengo otra inquietud, igual gracias por no ignorar la pregunta.

Comment: bro gracias al menos por responder algo gracias a lo que escribiste puede ver una especie de solución pero ahora tengo otra inquietud, igual gracias por no ignorar la pregunta.

Comment: Si quieres dar más detalles en tu pregunta, puedo intentar ayudarte, así puedes aceptar mi respuesta ;)